# How to test Pyramid security setup?

Tags: security, testing, pyramid

Is there a recommended way to test the security setup in a Pyramid application? More specifically I'm using routes and custom routes factories. With fine grained ACLs the security setup is splitted in different spots: the config setup, factories, permission set in the @view_config, and event explicit check of permissions inside views.

The page on unit and functionnal testing (http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/testing.html) does not seem to indicate a way to test if user A can only see and modify data he is allowed to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is functional testing. Webtest can preserve session cookies so you can use it to login and visit various pages as a user.

```
myapp = pyramid.paster.get_app('testing.ini')
app = TestApp(myapp)
resp = app.post('/login', params={'login': 'foo', 'password': 'seekrit'})
# this may be a redirect in which case you may want to follow it

resp = app.get('/protected/resource')
assert resp.status_code == 200
```

As far as testing just certain parts of your app, you can override the authentication policy with something custom (or just use a custom groupfinder).

```
def make_test_groupfinder(principals=None):
    def _groupfinder(u, r):
        return principals
    return _groupfinder
```

You can then use this function to simulate various principals. This doesn't handle the userid though, if your app also relies on `authenticated_userid(request)` anywhere. For that, you'll have to replace the authentication policy with a dummy one.

```
class DummyAuthenticationPolicy(object):
    def __init__(self, userid, extra_principals=()):
        self.userid = userid
        self.extra_principals = extra_principals

    def authenticated_userid(self, request):
        return self.userid

    def effective_principals(self, request):
        principals = [Everyone]
        if self.userid:
            principals += [Authenticated]
            principals += list(self.extra_principals)
        return principals

    def remember(self, request, userid, **kw):
        return []

    def forget(self, request):
        return []
```

Comment: I'm using mozilla persona for the login process. Do I need to create a fake login view solely for testing ?

Comment: You need a way to talk to your app as an authenticated user. The easiest way to get an authenticated user is to login. There are lots of other ways but they all basically involve you messing with how your app determines a logged-in user (something testing.ini can help you setup).

Answer (score 0):

I think both the question and answer might be old at this point: with current versions of Pyramid, there's a `testing_securitypolicy` method ([docs here](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/config.html#pyramid.config.Configurator.testing_securitypolicy)) that allows easy access to setting things like authenticated_userid, effective_principals, results of remember and forget, etc.

Here's an example of usage if need was to set `authenticated_userid` on a request.

```
from pyramid.testing import (setUp, tearDown, DummyRequest)

def test_some_view():
    config = setUp()
    config.testing_securitypolicy(userid='mock_user')  # Sets authenticated_userid

    dummy_request = DummyRequest()
    print(dummy_request.authenticated_userid)  # Prints 'mock_user'

    # Now ready to test something that uses request.authenticated_userid
    from mypyramidapp.views.secure import some_auth_view
    result = some_auth_view(dummy_request)
    expected = 'Hello mock_user!'
    assert result == expected

    # Finally, to avoid security changes leaking to other tests, use tearDown
    tearDown()  # Undo the effects of pyramid.testing.setUp()
```